# How do I fetch multiple columns for use in a cursor loop?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

When I try to run the following SQL snippet inside a cursor loop,

```
set @cmd = N'exec sp_rename ' + @test + N',' +
           RIGHT(@test,LEN(@test)-3) + '_Pct' + N',''COLUMN'''
```

I get the following message,

> Msg 15248, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_rename, Line 213
>      Either the parameter `@objname` is ambiguous or the claimed `@objtype` (COLUMN) is wrong.

What is wrong and how do I fix it ? I tried wrapping the column name in brackets `[]`, and double quotes `""` like some of the search results suggested.

Edit 1 -

Here is the entire script. How do I pass the table name to the rename sp ? I'm not sure how to do that since the column names are in one of many tables.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @cnt int
declare @test nvarchar(128)
declare @cmd nvarchar(500) 
declare Tests cursor for
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'pct%' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TestData%'

open Tests
fetch next from Tests into @test
while @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN
  set @cmd = N'exec sp_rename ' + @test + N',' + RIGHT(@test,LEN(@test)-3) + '_Pct' + N', column' 

  print @cmd

  EXEC sp_executeSQL @cmd

  fetch next from Tests into @test
END

close Tests 
deallocate Tests


ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
--COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Edit 2 - 
The script is designed to rename columns whose names match a pattern, in this case with a "pct" prefix. The columns occur in a variety of tables within the database. All table names are prefixed with "TestData".

Comment: this line concatenates a string. why don't you print it out so you can see what the string's contents are,

Comment: `@test` has the [form of `table.column` or `schema.table.column`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188351.aspx), doesn't it?

Comment: If @test contains qualified name it needs to be in apostrophes. If the same assumption holds, right() will remove first three characters in table name; in you wanted to replace last characters of column name this would be `LEFT`. Could you please expand the script a bit by adding set @test = ...?

Comment: Your code actually helped me solve my problem - thanks for that!

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Here is slightly modified version. Changes are noted as code commentary.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

declare @cnt int
declare @test nvarchar(128)
-- variable to hold table name
declare @tableName nvarchar(255)
declare @cmd nvarchar(500) 
-- local means the cursor name is private to this code
-- fast_forward enables some speed optimizations
declare Tests cursor local fast_forward for
 SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME
   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'pct%' 
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'TestData%'

open Tests
-- Instead of fetching twice, I rather set up no-exit loop
while 1 = 1
BEGIN
  -- And then fetch
  fetch next from Tests into @test, @tableName
  -- And then, if no row is fetched, exit the loop
  if @@fetch_status <> 0
  begin
     break
  end
  -- Quotename is needed if you ever use special characters
  -- in table/column names. Spaces, reserved words etc.
  -- Other changes add apostrophes at right places.
  set @cmd = N'exec sp_rename ''' 
           + quotename(@tableName) 
           + '.' 
           + quotename(@test) 
           + N''',''' 
           + RIGHT(@test,LEN(@test)-3) 
           + '_Pct''' 
           + N', ''column''' 

  print @cmd

  EXEC sp_executeSQL @cmd
END

close Tests 
deallocate Tests

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
--COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Comment: One of my favorite answers in SO.

Comment: @RubensMariuzzo Thanks, you are being too generous :-)

Comment: TLDR;
    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO `@var1, `@var2

Comment: TLDR is commonly used to indicate a short version of a longer piece of information. It stands for Too Long Didn't Read.
I was suggesting that there is a shorter version of the answer that you gave and I gave it.

Comment: Nice Touch, not fetching twice. :)

Comment: @winner_joiner not fetching twice, but now checking two conditions...not getting something for nothing.

Comment: I appreciate the wrapping in a transaction and defaulting to rollback so you have to comment/uncomment to commit.
<soapbox>Infinite loops are dangerous at best. The next person behind you may not understand the exit condition.</soapbox> - YMMV.

Comment: Are the '@' symbols required for any of these variables?  Or is that just personal style?

Comment: @devdanke variable names must begin with @. Please see [declare statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)