# How to create a WHILE loop in SQL and avoid Subquery error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am going to find the best coefficient `(Z)` for the following equation:

```
[Target] = Z * SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))
```

I have about 100,000 rows in my data-set which do not meet the `Target` level. So, I am going to find the minimum `Z` value to pass the target level. Each row is identical so one row might need `Z=34.5` and another one might need `Z=13.5`. I want to write a code to examine each row through a loop until all rows meet the desired target level and print the optimum `Z` values for all rows.

I wrote code like this:

```
While (Select [Target] From dbo.product) < 1000 
Begin
   Update dbo.product 
   SET [Z] = Z + 0.5

   Update dbo.product 
   SET [Target] = Z * SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))

   IF (Select [Target] From dbo.product) > 1000
      Break
   Else
      Continue 
End
```

Once I run this query, I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Do you have any idea how can I fix this error? And also do you believe this code could solve my problem? I appreciate your help!

Comment: `(Select [Target] From dbo.product)` returns a recordset and you can't compare a recordset with a integer.

Comment: You can use COUNT function as COUNT(Target)

Comment: @ydoow Thank you for your comment. Actually I saw Microsoft example for While function and there was almost same comparison. `(SELECT AVG(ListPrice) FROM Production.Product) < $300`

Comment: Note in your example `SELECT AVG(ListPrice)` always return a single value, rather than a record set.

Comment: If you're sure there's only single row in the table, you can use `SELECT TOP 1 [Target] From dbo.product` to make sure it's taking a single value for comparison.

Comment: @ydoow You are right the AVG refer to a single value. My data-set in not include only one row. So how can I create a loop in this case?

Comment: @Ashkan so what do you want to use to compare against `1000`? Is that the number of record / the average value of all `Target` column / the maximum or minimum value of `Target`? Or you want to iterate over each row?

Comment: @ydoow I want to compare each row in the `Target` column with `1000`. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ydoow I need a loop update on all records until `Target` is greater than 1000.

Comment: So it should be `While (Select MIN([Target]) From dbo.product) < 1000` since you want to make sure all `[Target]` is `>= 1000`

Comment: It makes sense. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: If you're going to treat a database table like a spreadsheet, you'd be better off using a genuine spreadsheet product. Ideally, in SQL, you generate set-based solutions (i.e. here it sounds like you ought to have a table of all possible `Z` values and then *join* the two tables together with a suitable condition such that you select the lowest `Z` value that matches your criteria for each row).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to make sure all rows with `[Target] >= 1000`, use `MIN` to find the row with smallest value.

```
While (Select MIN([Target]) From dbo.product) < 1000 
Begin
   Update dbo.product 
   SET [Z] = Z + 0.5
   WHERE [Target] < 1000

   Update dbo.product 
   SET [Target] = Z * SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))

   IF (Select MIN([Target]) From dbo.product) > 1000
      Break
   Else
      Continue 
End
```

Comment: I have a problem here. This code updating all `Z` at each iteration. It means at the end it gives a unique `Z` value for all rows. While I am looking for the minimum `Z` for each row which lead to `Target` greater than `1000`. Could you help me please to deal with this problem?

Comment: So in the first query you may only want to update the row where `[Target]` doesn't meet your target, and will be involved in the update. I've revised the answer for your reference. You may also want to put the same `WHERE` clause in the second query to have better performance.

Comment: It seems like the `If (condition) Break Else Continue` inside the `While` loop is superfluous. It tests same condition as in the `While`.

Comment: @spencer7593 you're right. I just keep the lines there in case if OP puts it there for a reason.

Answer (score 2):

You want to iterate over every record in the `dbo.product` table, and update the `Z` and `Target` columns based on a condition.  Appreciate that the only real purpose of the loop, from what I can see, is to find a value of `Z` which is large enough to cause the loop to exit and make the assignments.  But we can actually come up with a formula for what the value of `Z` should be for each record, without explicitly iterating with a loop:

```
[Target] = Z * SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))
```

The loop will break when `[Target]` exceeds `1000`, which leads to the following inequality:

```
1000 < Z * SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))
```

But we can solve for `Z`, leading to this inequality:

```
Z > 1000 / SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))
```

The only remaining trick is that `Z` comes in increments of `0.5`, so we should therefore round *up* to the nearest `0.5`.  We can use this formula for `Z` to solve for the corresponding value of `Target`.  This leads to the following code, which does not require any sort of loop:

```
GO
BEGIN
    UPDATE dbo.product 
    SET [Z] = FLOOR((1000 / SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2)) + 0.4) * 2) / 2
    UPDATE dbo.product 
    SET [Target] = [Z] * SQRT(Mu_L * POWER(Sigma_D,2) + POWER(Mu_D,2) * POWER(Sigma_L,2))
END
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this smart solution. But I need to calculate some other parameters at each iteration and for this reason I need to create a loop. I will appreciate it if you could help me to figure it out.

Comment: Fair enough.  The error you are getting is because your `SELECT` returns more than one record (all records, actually).  You need to iterate over the records instead.

Comment: Now I understood what is wrong here! Yes `select` returns all records. But do you have any idea how can I iterate over the records?

Comment: @Ashkan Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20662356/sql-server-loop-how-do-i-loop-through-a-set-of-records).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!