# SQL want to compare value in one cell with part of value in other cell

Tags: sql-server

I have

**Table XXX**

```
ID int
CODE varchar
```

**Table YYY**

```
ID int
X_ID int
```

A delimiter error in my import caused some records to get in my table twice. What happened? I am not sure. This is the result: both records in table XXX refer to the same entity, as the part of the CODE before the ';' is the same.

**TABLE XXX**

```
ID   | Code
123  | 456
789  | 456;li
```

**TABLE YYY**

```
ID   | X_ID
111  | 789
222  | 123
333  | 000
```

Now I need a query that does this for all 2900 records I need to update:
I need to keep all records in YYY.

> Update X_ID of record 111 in table YYY to 123 and then throw away record 789 from
>   table XXX

No need to do it in 1 query, though.
So how can I do that? Can you help me?
I have writte lots of half queries, and I feel like a noob (which I am in SQL)

Comment: I edited it a bit as a result of the answers given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made a mistake in my previous answer, as the solution I gave was for Oracle Database. The OP needs a solution for sqlserver.

I've translated my code to sql:

```
begin transaction
declare @good_id int
declare @bad_id int
declare @code varchar(128)

--update xxx as to change the lines containing ';' to just the number value. we do this by removing
--every character after ';' including ';'.
--we will use the updated values to calculate min and max over the id column
update XXX set code=SUBSTRING(code,1,CHARINDEX(';',code) - 1) where CHARINDEX(';',code)>0

--declare a cursor to calculate min (the good_id) and max (the bad_id) for a given code in table XXX
--this assumes the wrong id is always inserted secondly, i.e. it's value is always greater than the good id
declare myCursor cursor local fast_forward for
SELECT MIN (id) AS good_id, MAX (id) AS bad_id, code
                     FROM xxx
                 GROUP BY code
                   HAVING COUNT (1) = 2 --this condition is used to filter only duplicate entries, i.e only those entries in XXX that have the same code twice!

open myCursor

while 1=1 --while true
BEGIN
    fetch next from myCursor into @good_id, @bad_id, @code --save the values obtained from the cursor in local variables
    if @@FETCH_STATUS<>0 --when there is nothing left to fetch from the cursor we exit the while loop
    begin
        break
    end

    --update YYY with the correct values by using min/max(id) from the variables @good_id and @bad_id
    update YYY set x_id=@good_id where x_id=@bad_id;        
END --end while loop

close myCursor
deallocate myCursor

--delete the duplicates from XXX, i.e the bad entries represented by MAX
delete from XXX where id in(
select id from (
SELECT id,code,MAX (id) OVER (PARTITION BY code) as max_id FROM xxx) x where id=max_id)

commit transaction --save changes
```

Tested the code on this set of data:

```
Table XXX

id  code
123 456
456 999
789 456;li
932 999;ab
```

```
Table YYY

id  x_id
111 789
222 123
333 000
444 932
555 456
```

After running it:

```
Table XXX

id  code
123 456
456 999
```

```
Table YYY

id  x_id
111 123
222 123
333 000
444 456
555 456
```

OP, please let me know if it worked for you. If you have any questions regarding the code I will gladly answer them.

Answer (score 1):

This is what i came up with.
It turned out that there was an additional table that needed updating. 
Thank you, again, MiHaiC for your effort. I have been inspired by your answer.

```
WITH WA AS (
SELECT ID AS BID,
    Code AS BCode 
    FROM XXX
)

SELECT  a.id as 'FOUT_ID', 
    b.Bid as 'GOED_ID', 
    a.code as 'FOUTE_CODE', 
    b.Bcode as 'GOEDE_CODE'
    INTO TEST_QUERY
    from XXX a
    INNER JOIN WA b ON b.BCode = substring (a.code, 1, charindex (';', a.code,0 ) - 1)
    where a.prs_Code like '%;%'

UPDATE YYY
    SET X_ID = TEST_QUERY.GOED_ID
    FROM YYY
        INNER JOIN TEST_QUERY ON TEST_QUERY.FOUT_ID = X_ID
    WHERE ID IN (
        SELECT ID
        FROM ZZZ
            INNER JOIN TEST_QUERY ON TEST_QUERY.FOUT_ID = ZZZ.ID)

UPDATE ZZZ
    SET ID = TEST_QUERY.GOED_ID
    FROM ZZZ
        INNER JOIN TEST_QUERY ON TEST_QUERY.FOUT_ID = D_Melding.mld_prs_ID
```

Hope this may help someone else.

Comment: glad to see you fixed your problem!

Answer (score 0):

**First query:**

```
UPDATE YYY SET X_ID=123 WHERE ID=111
```

Conversely you could also do `WHERE X_ID=789` and achieve the same result.

**Second query:**

```
DELETE FROM XXX WHERE ID=789
```

Comment: Thank you. I have like 2907 records that i need to update. I would prefer a query that compares the two values automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it took a bit, the only fast solution I found, as in not to keep you waiting is by using a procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE FIX_XXX_YYY
IS
BEGIN
   --make changes in XXX, to remove delimiter, such that we can get min/max with group by code
   UPDATE XXX
      SET code = SUBSTR (code, 1, INSTR (code, ';') - 1)
    WHERE INSTR (code, ';') > 0;

   COMMIT;

   --update YYY with the correct values by using min/max(id) from XXX, min = first entry so the good one, max =bad entry.
   --basically update all bad entries in YYY with corresponding good value in XXX
   FOR entry IN (  SELECT MIN (id) AS good_id, MAX (id) AS bad_id, code
                     FROM xxx
                 GROUP BY code
                   HAVING COUNT (1) > 1)
   LOOP
      UPDATE yyy
         SET x_id = entry.good_id
       WHERE x_id = entry.bad_id;

      COMMIT;
   END LOOP;

   --delete the duplicates from XXX, i.e the bad entries represented by MAX
   DELETE FROM xxx
         WHERE id IN (SELECT id
                        FROM (SELECT id,
                                     code,
                                     MAX (id) OVER (PARTITION BY code) max_id
                                FROM xxx)
                       WHERE id = max_id);

   COMMIT;

   RETURN;
END FIX_XXX_YYY;
```

Call it by using:

```
BEGIN 
  FIX_XXX_YYY;
  COMMIT; 
END;
```

Hopefully I got it right this time. Please test and let me know. I will remove the bad answer.

Comment: instr(text,char) returns index of found char in the string text.

Comment: Thanks, MiHaic. I tried and I tried, and finally found how to save a stored procedure. Trying to get the right tuples in, but it wont run, as but INSTR and SUBSTR are 'not recognised as a built in function name'. (whatever that may mean).

Comment: i found 'charindex' as an alternative to instr. now trying to find something to replace substr.

Comment: FOR entry IN ( -> "incorrect syntax near 'in', expecting ID

Comment: tomorrow a friend of mine comes over and we will try to find a solution together. I am sorry that i could not use your solution, MiHaic. But it did inspire me to write a similar query, but it is still a tad wrong. I will be getting there, so thanks again for getting me in the right direction! Much appreciated.

Comment: i am sorry, i didn't read the tag properly. this code will only work for oracle database :) I will try tomorrow to rewrite it for sqlserver. You could try to rewrite my procedures in sql, instr is charIndex and substr = substring

Comment: @KimAlders You could translate the for loop into a WHILE statement and use cursors to get the data. more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11035187/how-do-i-fetch-multiple-columns-for-use-in-a-cursor-loop

Comment: @KimAlders check my new answer, I wrote the sql code